# Evaluate $\int\limits_{z=0}^4 \int\limits_{x =0}^{x =2\sqrt{z}}\int\limits_{y =0}^{y = \sqrt{4z -x^2}} dy dx dz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have been asked to find the triple Integral :

$\displaystyle \int_{z=0}^{4} \int_{x =0}^{x =2\sqrt{z}}\int_{y =0}^{y = \sqrt{4z -x^2}} dy dx dz$

Now $ 0 \le z \le 4$ , $0 \le x \le 2\sqrt{z}$, $0 \le y \le \sqrt{4z -x^2}$

Using this  I get :

$0 \le x \le 4$ , $0 \le y \le \sqrt{16-x^2}$,

Now for the Limits of $z$, I get:

$z \le 4$ and $y \le \sqrt{4z -x^2}$  this gives :

$\dfrac{x^2 +y^2}{4} \le z \le 4$ ,

So, the triple Integral Transforms to :

$\displaystyle \int_{x =0}^{x =4} \int_{y =0}^{y =\sqrt{16-x^2}} \int_{z = x^2 +y^2/4}^{4} dz dy dx$

My question is :

Is my solution upto this point correct ? After this step I can easily use polar coordinates to simplify this integral.

Can anyone please check whether my setup of the triple integral correct or Not ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your first two inequalities you find that
$$
0\leqslant x\leqslant 2\sqrt{z}\leqslant 4\iff 0\leqslant x^2\leqslant 4z\leqslant 16\\
\iff -x^2\leqslant 0\leqslant 4z-x^2\leqslant 16-x^2\tag1
$$
and from the third
$$
0\leqslant y^2\leqslant 4z-x^2\leqslant 16-x^2\iff x^2\leqslant y^2+x^2\leqslant 4z\leqslant 16\tag2
$$
Now suppose that you want $x$ as the free variable, then from the first inequality in $\rm(1)$ you have that $0\leqslant x\leqslant 4$, next suppose that you want to choose $y$ just depending on $x$, then from the last original inequality and the inequalities on $\rm(2)$ you have that $0\leqslant y\leqslant \sqrt{16-x^2}$.

Finally we have that $\tfrac{x^2}4\leqslant z\leqslant 4$ and $\tfrac{x^2+y^2}{4}\leqslant z\leqslant 4$ must hold, thus we choose the second inequality. Then the integral becomes
$$
\int_{0}^4\int_{0}^{\sqrt{16-x^2}}\int_{\frac{x^2+y^2}{4}}^{4}\,\mathrm d z\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x
$$
So, yes, your change of variables seems correct.